# Confusing about JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I want to JPQL likes following example:

Let Hotel object has two objects of Customer and Organization. If Customer is not null, organization will be null. And if the Customer is null , organization will not be null. So

I JPQL likes this;

> Select h.customer.name.firstName, h.organization.name from Hotel h

i want to assign one of these two result only to one variable because one is always null.
Thanks and Sorry for my english.

Comment: Please somebody answer me

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you are looking for `COALESCE()` function. Try the following:

```
SELECT COALESCE(h.customer.name.firstName, h.organization.name) FROM Hotel h
```

You also can use `CASE` expression if you want.

More details: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#d5e3257

Comment: Could you show us your code? Also you could try to enable logging of SQL statements (something like `hibernate.show_sql` in `persistence.xml`) and check resulted SQL query.

Comment: Here's my sql statements  "SELECT CASE  WHEN (t1.FIRSTNAME IS NOT NULL) THEN t1.FIRSTNAME WHEN (t2.NAME IS NOT NULL) THEN t2.NAME ELSE ? END FROM HOTEL t0, ORGANIZATION t2, CUSTOMER t1 WHERE ((t1.ID = t0.CUSTOMERID) AND (t2.ID = t0.ORGANIZATIONID))"

Answer (score 0):

You can select both fields & then can check for null values in code, else you can try using case statement, selecting non-null value.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (h.customer.name.firstName NOT NULL) THEN h.customer.name.firstName
            WHEN (h.organization.name NOT NULL) THEN h.organization.name 
            ELSE DEFAULT_VALUE 
       END 
FROM Hotel h
```

*[I haven't tried executing it, you can try it with modifications as required]*