# How to write hql subquery in case when then?

Tags: java, hql

```
SELECT rd.rdKey AS rdKey,
(
    CASE
      WHEN 
          replace (translate(rd.rdOpr1Value,'0123456789','0000000000'),'0','') is null
      THEN  
          COALESCE
          (
             SELECT c.isForeighn FROM ColumnMap c WHERE                              c.columnmapkey=rd.rdOpr1Value,'N'
          )
      ELSE 'N'
   END
) AS foreignYN,
rd.rdSetNO AS rdSetNO,
rd.createdUser AS createdUser,
rd.createdDateTime AS createdDateTime,
rd.updatedUser AS updatedUser,
rd.updatedDateTime AS updatedDateTime
FROM RuleDetail rd 
where rd.rdKey = 1;
```

For the above query i am getting error

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.identPrimary(HqlBaseParser.java:4341)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.primaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:948)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.atom(HqlBaseParser.java:3750)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.unaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3513)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.whenClause(HqlBaseParser.java:3887)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.caseExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3553)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.unaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3475)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.multiplyExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3380)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.additiveExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3073)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.concatenation(HqlBaseParser.java:632)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.relationalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2836)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.equalityExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2692)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.negatedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2651)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalAndExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2562)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalOrExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2522)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.expression(HqlBaseParser.java:2283)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.expressionOrVector(HqlBaseParser.java:4583)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.primaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:1035)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.atom(HqlBaseParser.java:3750)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.unaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3513)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.multiplyExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3380)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.additiveExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3073)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.concatenation(HqlBaseParser.java:632)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.relationalExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2836)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.equalityExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2692)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.negatedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2651)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalAndExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2562)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.logicalOrExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2522)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.expression(HqlBaseParser.java:2283)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.aliasedExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:2470)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectedPropertiesList(HqlBaseParser.java:1593)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectClause(HqlBaseParser.java:1486)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectFrom(HqlBaseParser.java:1208)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.queryRule(HqlBaseParser.java:774)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.selectStatement(HqlBaseParser.java:313)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlBaseParser.statement(HqlBaseParser.java:161)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:274)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:182)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:98)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
>     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1760)
>     at
>   fts.hrms.HRSetUp.UserAdmin.dao.RuleDetailDAO.getObjectByKey(RuleDetailDAO.java:158)
>     at
>   fts.hrms.HRSetUp.UserAdmin.service.RuleDetailService.getRuleDetailByKey(RuleDetailService.java:73)
>     at
>   fts.hrms.HRSetUp.UserAdmin.service.RuleDetailService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$ffaad115.invoke()
>     at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
>     at
>   fts.hrms.HRSetUp.UserAdmin.service.RuleDetailService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$118607e8_2.getRuleDetailByKey()
>     at
>   fts.hrms.HRSetUp.UserAdmin.controller.RuleDetailController.getRuleDetailByKey(RuleDetailController.java:72)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:585)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:322)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:155)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   fts.hrms.HRSetUp.UserAdmin.dao.RuleDetailDAO.getObjectByKey(RuleDetailDAO.java:165)
>     at
>   fts.hrms.HRSetUp.UserAdmin.service.RuleDetailService.getRuleDetailByKey(RuleDetailService.java:73)
>     at
>   fts.hrms.HRSetUp.UserAdmin.service.RuleDetailService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$ffaad115.invoke()
>     at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:191)  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(Cglib2AopProxy.java:688)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>     at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:108)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
>     at
>   fts.hrms.HRSetUp.UserAdmin.service.RuleDetailService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$118607e8_2.getRuleDetailByKey()
>     at
>   fts.hrms.HRSetUp.UserAdmin.controller.RuleDetailController.getRuleDetailByKey(RuleDetailController.java:72)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:669)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:585)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:322)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
>     at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:155)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Similar post, can refer - http://stackoverflow.com/q/23774916/366964

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not supported in Hibernate. 
But there does exist a workaround.
Create a view in the database and then use HQL to fetch result through java.

create or replace force view VW_ENTITY_VALUE(entityValue)
as
select case when a.entityId is null then 'invalid' else 
   (select b.entityName from tblName b where b.entityId =a.entityId) 
   end from tblEntity a;

From documentation of HQL:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries

14.13. Subqueries

For databases that support subselects, Hibernate supports subqueries within queries. A subquery must be surrounded by parentheses (often by an SQL aggregate function call). Even correlated subqueries (subqueries that refer to an alias in the outer query) are allowed.

from Cat as fatcat
where fatcat.weight > (
    select avg(cat.weight) from DomesticCat cat
)
from DomesticCat as cat
where cat.name = some (
    select name.nickName from Name as name
)
from Cat as cat
where not exists (
    from Cat as mate where mate.mate = cat
)
from DomesticCat as cat
where cat.name not in (
    select name.nickName from Name as name
)
select cat.id, (select max(kit.weight) from cat.kitten kit)
from Cat as cat
***Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses.***